# Access Violation while reading error on zlib for gzip

Tags: c, gzip, zlib

I am trying to decompress a binary buffer in c using zlib

```
BOOL gzipInflate(char* lpFileIn, DWORD lpFileInSize) {
    z_stream strm;
    char* uncomp, * uncomp2;
    unsigned int uncompLength, half_length;
    int err;
    bool done = false;

    uncompLength = lpFileInSize;
    half_length = lpFileInSize / 2;

    uncomp = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char), uncompLength);

    memset(&strm, 0, sizeof(strm));

    strm.next_in = (Bytef*)lpFileIn;
    strm.avail_in = (uInt)lpFileInSize;
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    strm.total_out = Z_NULL;


    if (inflateInit2(&strm, 16 + MAX_WBITS) != Z_OK) {
        free(uncomp);
        return FALSE;
    }

    while (!done)
    {

        if (strm.total_out >= uncompLength) {
            uncomp2 = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char), uncompLength + half_length);
            memcpy(uncomp2, uncomp, uncompLength);
            uncompLength += half_length;
            free(uncomp);
            uncomp = uncomp2;
        }

        strm.next_out = (Bytef*)(uncomp + strm.total_out);
        strm.avail_out = uncompLength - strm.total_out;


        err = inflate(&strm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);

        if (err == Z_STREAM_END) {
            done = true;
        }
        else if (err != Z_OK) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (inflateEnd(&strm) != Z_OK) {
        free(uncomp);
        return FALSE;
    }

    free(uncomp);

    return TRUE;
}
```

I get access violation while reading with a random address
Also i am using 'GZipStream' from .NET to compress the buffer and decompressing it using C

Orignal Code: https://windrealm.org/tutorials/decompress-gzip-stream.php

Comment: Which exact line of code triggers the access violation? Running the program in a debugger will immediately tell you that. Then you can continue to use the debugger to trace and examine the code. That's the best way to do debugging. If you really need help from Stackoverflow then please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: inflate(&strm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH); triggers the access violation

Comment: So why not stepping into the function `inflate` and see where it happens more precisely ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean: I am sorry but this is a person project i am trying to learn gzlib over sockets after work i barely get 1.5 or 2 hours and i am not that much good at asm

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out when compiling zlib on visual studios for windows use "ReleaseWithoutAsm" rather than "Release" as `inflate_fast()` is buggy in asm